# define a type involving pattern matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I want to define a type in PostgreSQL where the type should look like :

```
[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}
```

which is doing a pattern matching.
What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE DOMAIN` might work for you.

```
create domain NEWTYPE as char(8)
  constraint newtype_regex not null check (value ~ '[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}');
```

I guessed about `not null`. Use it like an intrinsic data type.

```
create table test (
  nt NEWTYPE
);
```

Smoke test . . .

```
insert into test values ('ABCD0123'); -- Succeeds
insert into test values ('ABCD012');  -- Fails
insert into test values (null);       -- Fails
insert into test values ('abcd0123'); -- Fails
```